# Long author list goes below title page. How to use page break on authors or affiliations?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc, papaja

I've been trying to knit an article with a very long author list. Here I'm using apa6_pdf with papaja. However, the long list seems not to start on a new page. Half of them cannot be shown on the first page since it's too long. Is there any way to solve this?

Here's an easy replicate of the codes with the problem. Also with the generated pdf.

[generated pdf screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90nuH.png)

```
---
title             : " **Whole day tring to solve this problem**"

author: 
  - name: John M. Smith
    affiliation: '1'
    corresponding: yes
    address: Enter postal address here
  - name: Marton Kovacs
    affiliation: '2'
  - name: 1 1
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 2 2
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 3 3
    affiliation: '4'
  - name: 4 4
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 5 5
    affiliation: '5'
  - name: 6 6
    affiliation: '6'
  - name: 7 7
    affiliation: '4'
  - name: 8 8
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 9 9
    affiliation: '7'
  - name: 10 10
    affiliation: '8'
  - name: 11 11
    affiliation: '9'
  - name: 12 12
    affiliation: '10'
  - name: 13 13
    affiliation: '11'
  - name: 14 14
    affiliation: '1'
  - name: 15 15
    affiliation: '2'
  - name: 16 16
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 17 17
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 18 18
    affiliation: '4'
  - name: 19 19
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 20 20
    affiliation: '5'
  - name: 21 21
    affiliation: '6'
  - name: 22 22
    affiliation: '4'
  - name: 23 23
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 24 24
    affiliation: '7'
  - name: 25 25
    affiliation: '8'
  - name: 26 26
    affiliation: '9'
  - name: 27 27
    affiliation: '10'
  - name: 28 28
    affiliation: '11'
  - name: 29 29
    affiliation: '1'
  - name: 30 30
    affiliation: '2'
  - name: 31 31
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 32 32
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 33 33
    affiliation: '4'
  - name: 34 34
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 35 35
    affiliation: '5'
  - name: 36 36
    affiliation: '12'
  - name: 37 37
    affiliation: '13'
  - name: 38 38
    affiliation: '14'
  - name: 39 39
    affiliation: '15'
  - name: 40 40
    affiliation: '8'
  - name: 41 41
    affiliation: '16'
  - name: 42 42
    affiliation: '10'
  - name: 43 43
    affiliation: '11'
  - name: 44 44
    affiliation: '16'
  - name: 45 45
    affiliation: '2'
  - name: 46 46
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 47 47
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 48 48
    affiliation: '17'
  - name: 49 49
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 50 50
    affiliation: '7'
  - name: 51 51
    affiliation: '18'
  - name: 52 52
    affiliation: '4'
  - name: 53 53
    affiliation: '3'
  - name: 54 54
    affiliation: '7'
  - name: 55 55
    affiliation: '8'
  - name: 56 56
    affiliation: '9'
  - name: 57 57
    affiliation: '10'
  - name: 58 58
    affiliation: '11'
  - name: 59 59
    affiliation: '19'
  - name: 60 60
    affiliation: '20'

affiliation: 
  - id: '1'
    institution: School of Psychology, University of Sydney, Sydney, Australia
  - id: '2'
    institution: Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology
  - id: '3'
    institution: Institute of Psycchology, ELTE Eotvos Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology
  - id: '4'
    institution: Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologya
  - id: '5'
    institution: Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa
  - id: '6'
    institution: Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Laoranda University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology
  - id: '7'
    institution: Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa
  - id: '8'
    institution: Institute of Psycholaogy, ELTE Eotvos Laoranda University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology
  - id: '9'
    institution: Institute of Psycchology, ELTE Eotvos Lorand University, Budapaest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology
  - id: '10'
    institution: Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Lorand Universaity, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologya
  - id: '11'
    institution: Institute of Psycahology, ELTE Eotvos Loranda University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology
  - id: '12'
    institution: Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Laoran1da University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology
  - id: '13'
    institution: Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Loran2d University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologya
  - id: '14'
    institution: Institute of Psycchology, ELTE Eotvos Loran3d University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyInstitute of Psycchology, ELTE Eotvos
      Loran3d University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychology
  - id: '15'
    institution: Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of Psychologyaa
  - id: '16'
    institution: Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa
  - id: '17'
    institution: Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa
  - id: '18'
    institution: Institute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvos Laoranda University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa
  - id: '19'
    institution: aInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa
  - id: '20'
    institution: vInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas
      Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School of PsychologyaaInstitute
      of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest, Hungary, Doctoral School
      of PsychologyaaInstitute of Psychology, ELTE Eotvoas Lorand University, Budapest,
      Hungary, Doctoral School of Psychologyaa

class: "jou"
output        : papaja::apa6_pdf

---
```

I tried for hours to test. It actually works fine with `class: "man"`, which knits a manuscript instead. But it does work with `class: "jou"` , which knits in journal article format.

Comment: pandoc uses latex under the hood to create a PDF (see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf), so perhaps ask on https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can literally put latex into the configuration/yaml meta data. So I did something like this to desing a titlepage before:

```
title: |

    \vspace{-2cm}

    ![](templates/pics/fzjhhu.pdf)
    
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    \hrule
    \vspace{0.5cm}
 
    This is the title of the work innit
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \hrule
    
    \vspace{2.5cm}
    
    \begin{normalsize}
        \textbf{Doctoral thesis}

        \vspace{0.5cm}
        
        \textit{submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of}
        
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        
        \begin{large}\textbf{PhD in Medical Sciences}\end{large}
        
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        
        \textit{by}
    
    \end{normalsize}
```

So similar to me you can use latex code (begin{normalsize}) to make fontsizes smaller. Check info on font sizes here for example: https://latex-tutorial.com/changing-font-size/

I also wonder if there are ways for you to design the title page to remove some of the institution duplicates (if it doesn't have to be formatted exactly like that).

Something else I have done in the past was to use the authblk latex package to format institutions like so:

```
header-includes: |
 \usepackage{soul}  
 \usepackage[left]{lineno}
 \linenumbers
 
 \usepackage{authblk}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \onehalfspacing
 \usepackage{caption}
 \captionsetup{labelsep=period,labelfont=bf}
 \usepackage{hanging}
 \usepackage{helvet}
 \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
   
 \author[1, 2]{my name}
 \author[1, 2]{author name}
 \author[1, 2]{author name}
 \author[1, 2]{author name}
 \author[1, 2]{author name}
 \author[3]{author name}
 \author[1, 2]{author name}
 \author[1, 2]{author name \thanks{author email}}


 \affil[1]{Institute N1}
 \affil[2]{Institute N2}
 \affil[3]{Institute N3}
```

This solution avoids having the same institutions multiple times on the page and therefore will save some space on the title page. Of course this is only one way of formatting the title page and if you need a different one, this may not be right for you.

Comment: Latex font sizes are switches and not environments. While they more or less work by accident, it really should be `{\large ... }` etc.

Comment: What is the rationale behind not using them as environments? Simply "because that's not how one should do it" or because it can result in unexpected behaviour of some sort?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258281 interesting discussion